# C++: Updating pointers in deep copy (efficiently)

Tags: c++, pointers, deep-copy

My question is best illustrated with a code sample, so let's just start off with that:

```
class Game
{
    // All this vector does is establish ownership over the Card objects
    // It is initialized with data when Game is created and then is never
    // changed.
    vector<shared_ptr<Card> > m_cards;

    // And then we have a bunch of pointers to the Cards.
    // All these pointers point to Cards from m_cards.
    // These could have been weak_ptrs, but at the moment, they aren't
    vector<Card*> m_ptrs;

    // Note: In my application, m_ptrs isn't there, instead there are
    // pointers all over the place (in objects that are stored in member
    // variables of Game.
    // Also, in my application, each Card in m_cards will have a pointer
    // in m_ptrs (or as I said, really just somewhere), while sometimes
    // there is more than one pointer to a Card.
}
```

Now what I want to do is to make a deep copy of this Game class. I make a new vector with new shared_ptrs in it, which point to new Card objects which are copies of the original Card objects. That part is easy.

Then the trouble starts, the pointers of m_ptrs should be updated to point to the cards in m_cards, which is no simple task.

The only way I could think of to do this is to create a map and fill it during the copying of m_cards (with `map[oldPtr] = newPtr`) and then to use that to update m_ptrs. However, this is only `O(m * log(n))` (`m = m_ptrs.size(); n = m_cards.size()`). As this is going to be a pretty regular operation* I would like to do this efficiently, and I have the feeling that it should be possible in `O(m)` using custom pointers. However, I can't seem to find an efficient way of doing this. Anybody who does?

*it's used to create a testbed for the AI, letting it "try out" different moves

---

Edit: I would like to add a bit on accepting an answer, as I haven't yet. I am waiting until I get back to this project (I got on a side track as I had worked too much on this project - if you do it for fun it's got to stay fun), so it may be a while longer before I accept an answer. Nevertheless, I will accept an answer some time, so don't worry :P

---

Edit nr 2: I still haven't gotten back to this project. Right now, I am thinking about just taking the `O(m * log(n))` way and not complaining, then seeing later if it needs to be faster. However, as I have recently taken some time to learn my patterns, I am also thinking that I really need to refactor this project some time. Oh, and that I might just spend some time working on this problem with all the new knowledge I have under my belt. Since there isn't an answer that says "just stick with the hashmap and see later if it really needs to be faster" (and I would actually be pretty disappointed if there was, as it's not an answer to my question), I am postponing the picking of an answer yet a bit more till I do get back to this project.

---

Edit nr 3: I still didn't get back to this project. More precisely, it has been shelved indefinitely. I am pretty sure I just wouldn't get my head too bent over the `O(m * log(n))`right now, and then perhaps look at it later if it turned out to be a problem. However, that would just not have been a good answer to my question, as I explicitly asked for better performance. Not wanting to leave the answers unaccepted any longer, I chose the most helpful answer and accepted it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you think you need 2 vectors with the same data.  Sounds like a duplication of data defect to me.  Please explain why you need/want this?

Comment: @John Dibling: Please **DO** read. The array of pointers is a simplification to make the problem easier. In actuality it doesn't exist - instead the pointers are spread over a number of classes owned by Game. That was in the question. Also, it was (in more detail) elsewhere on this page.

Comment: I used exactly a map to map oldptrs to newptrs when doing something similar altough it didn't matter in my case since the map is only used on the time of copying so wasn't necessary to optimize. Do you think you can refactor your project to help make your change easier to introduce or something?

Comment: @n1ck: The thing is that the copying is the core part of the AI, which - in an application like this one - is most definitely a bottleneck. Basically even the effect of playing a single card isn't even known to the AI, so it will have to do a copy of the game in order to find it out. Then, playing a sequence of cards also requires a copy of the game to see the effects. Finally, to see the possible results of an intended plan yet again needs copying of the game. Basically, copying the game will be at the core of the AI.

Comment: @n1ck: I don't exactly understand what you mean when you want me to refactor the project. However, the usage of a different pointer class will minimize the number of changes I will have to make to the code. That is a nice bonus, though it wasn't truly a reason to suggest that approach - that was instigated by what appeared proper design to me (as the software is still in an early alpha phase and I do not have a deadline on it and because I am somewhat idealistic, I do prefer proper design).

Comment: @Jasper I think that you should start by getting the copying right and focus after on optimizing since it seems that it might be a problem for you. Personnally I used axter's smart pointer to handle deep copying and also used the following trick http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469696/what-is-your-most-useful-c-c-utility/1609496#1609496. Maybe this could be usefull to you. I think you won't have choice to create a function to update the references to the pointers though. A map worked well for me and could probably be optimized later.

Comment: @n1ck: I don't mind having to update this pointer, it's just that I will need to loop through the map (indirectly through find) to find the correct pointer, which I don't like. I have a feeling there is a better design. For designs I believe it's good to write your original design well, instead of optimizing later, which is the proper way to handle small changes. Also, because of how the pointers are spread through different classes, changing your design to optimize will be more complicated than it is in the actual sample code I gave above.

Comment: @n1ck: I don't see a point for using those smart pointers there. There is no advantage to using them in this problem. The trick you present is pretty bad: first off it works at runtime, while checking something that could be done at compile time. It increases the size of each of the objects in question needlessly. On top of that it introduces a pretty bad memory leak (bad because it is so often, not because it is by a lot per object).

Comment: @Jasper : sorry I think I might just misunderstood your problem, dismiss everything I said but I'm interested in your opinion about my trick. If you have time maybe you could comment my post I'm not sure to have followed you and we will get carried away from your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the pointers as indexes.
As you say they all point to m_Cards which is a vector that can be indexed (is that correct English?).
Either you do that only for storing and convert them back to pointers at loading.
Or you may think of using indices generally instead of pointers.

Comment: kaptnole, I've edited according to my browsers spillchucker. Oh, and `+1`, since I agree.

Comment: So basically, I create a pointer that stores a reference to a vector and an index. Sounds nice - if done properly it can probably be done with true pointer syntax. I'll need to look into the specifics, but it sounds good.

Comment: I am running in something of a problem due to the fact that besides using a number of Card*s I am also using a number of SpecialCard*s (where SpecialCard inherits from Card) which also point to members of m_cards and which should also be updated. To be honest, though, that was just not in the question.

Answer (score 0):

What about keeping cards elements index instead of pointer:

```
vector<int> m_indexes;

...

Card* ptr = &m_cards[m_indexes[0]];
```

Vector with indexes can be copied without changes.

Comment: I'm not sold on the solution, seeing that it would require me to hand out references to m_cards to dozens of classes, seeing that the card pointers aren't really used in the same class, but all over the place. It does solve the problem, though.

Comment: @Jasper Why do you have to hand out a reference to m_cards? Can't you still hand out actual pointers to other classes?

Comment: because the sample is simplified, the pointers don't actually reside in the same class - they reside in classes owned by Game - all of these pointers need to point to the new Card objects. So using indexes instead of pointers, but using pointers in classes other than the Game class (which like all but one of them :P) does not quite solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered the very similar problem: cloning the class internal structure implemented by pointers and std::vector as an objects storage.

First of all (unrelated to the question though), I'd suggest either stick with smart pointers or with plain structures. In your case it means that it makes much more sense to use `vector<weak_ptr<Card> > m_ptrs` instead of raw pointers.

About the question itself - one more possible workaround is using pointer differences in the copy constructor. I will demonstrate it for vector of objects, but working with shared pointers will utilize the same principle, the only difference will be in copying of m_cards (you should not simply use assignment if you want objects clones but copy the `m_cards` element-by-element).

It is **very important** that the method works only for containers where the elements are guaranteed to be stored consequently (vector, array).

Another **very important** moment is that the `m_ptrs` elements should represent only **internal** `Card` structrure, i. e. they must point only to the internal `m_cards` elements.

```
// assume we store objects directly, not in shared pointers
// the only difference for shared pointers will be in
// m_cards assignment
// and using m_cards[...].get() instead of &m_cards[...]
vector<Card> m_cards;
vector<Card*> m_ptrs;
```

In that case your array of pointers can be easily computed by using pointers arithmetic taking linear time. In that case your copy constructor will look like this:

```
Game::Game(const Game &rhs) {
  if (rhs.m_cards.empty())
    return;

  m_cards = rhs.m_cards;

  // if we have vector of shared pointers
  // and we need vector of pointers to objects clones
  // something like this should be done
  // for (auto p: rhs.m_cards) {
  //   // we must be certain here that dereferencing is safe,
  //   // i. e. object must exist. If not, additional check is required.
  //   // copy constructor will be called here:
  //   m_cards.push_back(std::make_shared<Card>(*p));
  // }

  Card *first = &rhs.m_cards[0];
  for (auto p: rhs.m_ptrs) {
    m_ptrs.push_back(&m_cards[p - first]);
  }
}
```

Basically in this deepcopy method you will be still working with indexes, but you preserve the convenience of working with pointers in other class methods without storing your indexes separately.

Anyway, for using that kind of structure you should exactly know what you are doing with the class members and why, that requires much more manual control (for example, at least adding/removing elements to/from `m_cards` should be done consciously, in other case `m_ptrs` can easily become broken even without copying the object).